# I don't understand result

Tags: c++

[image]

I thought result will be 
int     parameter  a : 3 3

but result was

[image]

why result is it?

Comment: First step: edit your question to include your actual code. Not a link to a picture somewhere.

Comment: That's because you didn't read stackoverflow.com's [help] that explains to you that all question on stackoverflow.com must include all pertinent information in the question itself, ***as plain text***.

Comment: You may wish to read what `endl` does.

Answer (score 0):

Where you call "cout << "int\t" << TestFunction(3) << endl;" it needs to evaluate the function call first, before it can print out "int\t (returned value)" The only way it will know what to print out is by running the function. When the function runs, it prints out "paramater a :". The three is then returned, and the second cout statement can be performed: (int\t)

Answer (score -1):

Ready steps

1. Ready to Print : "int     (value)"
2. TestFunc is called.
3. "parameter a: 3" is printed.
4. TestFunc returns value "3"
5. Ready to Print : "int     (value)" --> Print : "int      3"